# unit tests using StackExchange.Redis

Tags: .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using `StackExchange.Redis` in .NETCore project.

Now, I am supposed to add ConnectionMultiplexer object as singleton.
But then I am not able to write the unit tests.

In the documentation it recommends to spin up a redis docker container, but is it possible to have something like a in-memory db.
And then I can write my redis UT's.

This is also stopping me to do open telemetry istrumentation of Redis.

`services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("<redisConnectionString>"));`

I am expecting that when it builds, it should be able to run unit tests with in-memory db instead of using a docker container.

Anyways if you've done it with docker container, any reference to your code will also help.